# How to connect all points in a graph generated by a set of given vertexes?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, trees, nearest

I am trying to construct a tree by looking at the nearest neighbors (or just approximately nearest for higher efficient) of a set of given vertexes. I first try this:-

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[12]; pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]];
NearestNeighborGraph[pts, 1]
```

[image]

As you can see, there are 3 trees and they are not connected. I want to connect them in a way (or some other ways) similar to below:-

[image]

How can I get it done? Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called the Euclidean minimum spanning tree problem. The Euclidean minimum spanning tree is a subgraph of the Delaunay graph. Exploiting this, we can solve this as follows.

Generate points:

```
pts = RandomPoint[Disk[], 50]
```

Compute a Delaunay triangulation and retrieve it as a graph (using [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM), which needs to be installed first):

```
graph = IGMeshGraph@DelaunayMesh[pts]
```

[image]

Note that this is a weighted graph with the weights representing the edge lengths.

Find a minimum spanning tree (taking edge weights into account) and transfer the vertex coordinates from the original graph.

```
FindSpanningTree[graph, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[graph]]
```

[image]

This gives us the graph (tree) with the shortest total edge length that connects all of the points.

You may find it useful to use

```
IGSpanningTree[graph, VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[graph]]
```

instead, as this function preserves the edge weights (`FindSpanningTree` throws them away).

---

Here's a possible alternative for IGraph/M's `IGMeshGraph` function (so that you don't have to install IGraph/M just for this trivial task):

```
meshGraph[mesh_] := 
  Graph[
    Range@MeshCellCount[mesh, 0],
    MeshCells[mesh, 1][[All, 1]],
    EdgeWeight -> PropertyValue[{mesh, 1}, MeshCellMeasure],
    VertexCoordinates -> MeshCoordinates[mesh]
  ]
```

---

You may be interested in other proximity graph functions that IGraph/M has, such `IGLuneBetaSkeleton`, `IGRelativeNeighborhoodGraph`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Did I misunderstand something? It seems that I don't have the function `IGMeshGraph`. I am using Mathematica 11.2.

Comment: @HMC As I said, it is part of the IGraph/M package. But you can also implement your own mesh-to-graph conversion. IGraph/M is open source, so you can check how it does it.

Comment: @HMC Sorry, but at this point I can't be bothered to do any graph stuff without the convenience of IGraph/M :-P

Comment: @HMC I added a possible implementation of `IGMeshGraph` to avoid the impression that I'm trying to push my package on people (in reality I was just lazy, and I really don't do graph stuff without it anymore)

Comment: Thanks, and it really helps. I noted a typo of your function name, which I trust should be `IGMeshGraph ` instead of `meshGraph`. I tried to edit it for you, but my edit needs to be 6 characters at least so I can't submit the amendment. Please note.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with a disconnected graph add new edges to make the graph connected:

```
ClearAll[makeConnected]
makeConnected = If[ConnectedGraphQ @ #, #, 
 EdgeAdd[#, Join @@ UndirectedEdge @@@ MinimalBy[#, EuclideanDistance @@ # &]&/@
   Tuples /@ Partition[ConnectedComponents[#], 2, 1]]]&;
```

**Examples:**

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[12]; pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]];
nng = NearestNeighborGraph[pts, 1];

HighlightGraph[makeConnected @ nng, nng]
```

[image]

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[12]; pts2 = RandomReal[1, {40, 2}]];
nng2 = NearestNeighborGraph[pts2, 1];

HighlightGraph[makeConnected [nng2], nng2]
```

[image]

```
IsomorphicGraphQ[makeConnected @ nng2, FindSpanningTree[makeConnected @ nng2]]
```

> True

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to obtain the minimum spanning tree of the distance graph (i.e. the complete graph with edge-weights equal to the Euclidean distance between the points in your set), you can do so using built-in Mathematica functions like so

```
FindSpanningTree@WeightedAdjacencyGraph@Outer[Norm[#1 - #2] &, Points, Points,1]
```

I think the only part requiring some explanation is

```
Outer[Norm[#1 - #2] &, Points, Points,1]
```

which builds the distance graph adjacency matrix, and is equivalent to the more readable

```
Table[Norm[p1-p2],{p1,Points},{p2,Points}]
```

Comment: `DistanceMatrix` would be much faster (but still of $O(n^2)$ complexity). The purpose of using a Delaunay triangulation as the base graph was to avoid the $O(n^2)$ complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I didn't know about `DistanceMatrix`. I just thought I'd mention this because it was conceptually simpler and efficiency didn't seem the issue here...

Comment: Thanks for both. I tested some cases and recorded the timing. In 2D cases, seems that `WeightedAdjacencyGraph@Outer` is faster than `IGMeshGraph@DelaunayMesh` more than 10 times. My real case is a 3D case, in which `IGMeshGraph@DelaunayMesh` is faster than `WeightedAdjacencyGraph@Outer` 10 times.

Comment: @Szabolcs So I will use Delaunay triangulation in my case. May I ask what is the theorectical complexity of Delaunay triangulation?

Comment: Delaunay triangulation can be done in O(n log n), so it should be faster for large enough sets. As suggested by @Szabolcs , however, `DistanceMatrix` will be much faster than `Outer` even if it has the same O(n^2) complexity, so this is what you should compare to timingwise...